# regex - Finding pattern which can contain character but not end with it (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in regular expressions. I tried to find answer for my case, but failed miserably. I tried many ideas I found but it didn't worked for me.

I have a special repetitive pattern which I tried to match, and I did most of it by I cannot find exact solution. This is what I did:

**My RegEx**

```
/((([a-zA-IK-Z][a]?)[\d]{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?)(-)?){1,}/g
```

**My pattern:**

```
Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-Aa50   match (expected)
Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-A      doesn't match (expected)
Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-Aa     doesn't match (expected)
```

And for these cases it works very well, but I want it to not match next example:

```
Aa200-B300-M52A-     (ending with -)
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this pattern:

```
/^[a-zA-IK-Z]a?\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?(?:-[a-zA-IK-Z]a?\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?)*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kjrRwd/1)

By placing `-` at the start of repeating non-capturing group we make sure that `-` occurs only in the middle but not in the end.

Comment: I see that both yours and regex pattern of @rje do the job. Can one or both of you explain to me what is the advantage of one of this solutions? That would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure how other regex (in current form) is working for you. It requires start and end anchors to work. Even when you add anchor that regex is very long and inefficient. For same input [it takes 414 steps](https://regex101.com/r/kjrRwd/2) as compared to 167 in mine,

Comment: Ok, I understand now how it is better. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It defines that if there is a next group there should be a "-" before it. I also changed your number groups from {1,3} to {0,3} since your expected matches don't always have a number in them (2nd and 3rd case). Hope this helps!

```js
const regex = /^([a-zA-IK-Z]a?[\d]{0,3}[a-zA-Z]?)(-([a-zA-IK-Z]a?[\d]{0,3}[a-zA-Z]?))*$/;

console.log("Should match");
console.log("Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-Aa50".match(regex));
console.log("Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-A".match(regex));
console.log("Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-Aa".match(regex));

console.log("Should not match");
console.log("Aa200-B300-M52A-G5-".match(regex));
```